# C++ Builder bccarm error when calling std::vector::push_back with TObject descendant

Tags: android, c++, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I have some simple C++ code which won't be compiled by the Clang based C++11 compiler bccaarm of C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin.

This is the code:

```
TComponent* Comp = new TComponent(this);
std::vector<TComponent*> Comps;
Comps.push_back(Comp);
```

And this is the error:

> [bccaarm error] stl_iterator.h(963): rvalue reference to type
>   'value_type' (aka 'System: classes::TComponent * __strong') can not be
>   bound to lvalue of type '__borland_class * isTObj __strong' (aka
>   'System::Classes::TComponent * __strong')

The compiler stops at line 963 in the file stl_iterator.h:

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

The other C++ compilers bcc32 and bcc32c(also Clang based) have no problems with this code.

When `Comp`is not from type `TComponent` or another descendant from `TObject` the code compiles without any problem.

I have no idea what is wrong with this code and why there is a problem with R and L values...

Does anybody know what to do here?

Comment: The English translation would be something like this: `[bccaarm error] stl_iterator.h(963): rvalue reference to type 'value_type' (aka 'System: classes::TComponent * __strong') can not be bound to lvalue of type '__borland_class * isTObj __strong' (aka 'System::Classes::TComponent * __strong')`  The mobile compilers, like bccaarm, implement Object ARC (that is where the `__strong` comes into play), but the desktop compilers do not, which is why the code compiles in bcc32 and bcc32c.

Comment: I would expect this code to compile fine under ARC, though I find it weird that `std::vector::iterator::operator*` is using `std::move()` at all. The operator is supposed to return a reference to an existing item in the vector, there should be no moving involved. Maybe an STL bug?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Adding __unsafe helped (see answer) but it's still not clear if there is a bug in the STL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the above code compiled the vector type has to be defined as an unsafe pointer.

```
TComponent* Comp = new TComponent(this);
std::vector<__unsafe TComponent*> Comps;
Comps.push_back(Comp);
```

I openened a support case for an other problem I had. The embarcadero support gave me the following information which I applied to this problem and it seems to work:

> `__unsafe` tells the compiler that object lifetimes will be handled and no ARC code is generated for the objects

More about this topic:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_C%2B%2B#weak_and_unsafe_pointers